Ghost row counts after DBCC CLONEDATABASE?
According to the Microsoft SQL Server documentation for DBCC CLONEDATABASE,

Generates a schema-only, read-only copy of a database by using DBCC
CLONEDATABASE in order to investigate performance issues related to
the query optimizer.

I'm finding the cloned database shows ghost row counts for the tables even though there is no data present.
Platform: Windows Server 2019 Standard / SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition
Query number of rows in each table:
SELECT T.NAME TABLENAME, I.ROWS RECORDS
FROM SYSOBJECTS T
INNER JOIN SYSINDEXES I ON (I.ID = T.ID AND I.INDID IN (0,1))
WHERE T.XTYPE = 'U'
ORDER BY TABLENAME;




SOURCE_DB
ROW_COUNT




dbo.TABLE_A
772


dbo.TABLE_B
0


dbo.TABLE_C
4


dbo.TABLE_D
323



DBCC CLONEDATABASE ([SOURCE_DB], [CLONE_DB]) WITH NO_STATISTICS

No rows are returned from the tables in the cloned database, which is correct.
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.TABLE_A;

However, querying for record counts show number of rows equal to that of the source database. Rebuilding the indexes and statistics doesn't update the results.



CLONE_DB
ROW_COUNT




dbo.TABLE_A
772


dbo.TABLE_B
0


dbo.TABLE_C
4


dbo.TABLE_D
323




What do you mean, exactly (can you update the OP with an actual example), when you say, "I'm finding the cloned database contains data from the source".

I was not able to reproduce this issue with the default parameters. How many rows are you seeing in your user tables?

I've updated the question and added more detail. The tables appear to be empty in the cloned database, but positive row counts are showing. I'm calling these ghost row counts.

behaving as expected
The documentation and examples are decently specific in this case.

NO_STATISTICS Applies to: SQL Server 2014 (12.x) Service Pack 2 CU 3,
SQL Server 2016 (13.x) Service Pack 1, and later versions.
Specifies if table/index statistics need to be excluded from the
clone. If this option isn't specified, table/index statistics are
automatically included.

And later, from the examples:

A. Create a clone of a database that includes schema, statistics and
Query Store The following example creates a clone of the
AdventureWorks2022 database that includes schema, statistics and Query
Store data (SQL Server 2016 (13.x) Service Pack 1 and later versions):

DBCC CLONEDATABASE (AdventureWorks2022, AdventureWorks_Clone);
    GO

Doing this will create a clone of your database including statistical information about what data resides in your tables. This includes row counts and histograms, and is useful for reproducing some performance issues for troubleshooting.
If you don't want that, you would need to follow the script from the line immediately below that example:

B. Create a schema-only clone of a database without statistics The
following example creates a clone of the AdventureWorks2022 database
that doesn't include statistics (SQL Server 2014 (12.x) Service Pack 2
CU 3 and later versions):

DBCC CLONEDATABASE (AdventureWorks2022, AdventureWorks_Clone) WITH NO_STATISTICS;
GO


I had tried before using "WITH NO_STATISTICS, NO_QUERYSTORE, VERIFY_CLONEDB, BACKUP_CLONEDB" with the same results: invalid row counts in the cloned database. I tried again with just "WITH NO_STATISTICS", and I still have invalid row counts.

@ErikAnderson either you're doing something really weird to have that happen to you (I say that in the nicest way possible, because I can't reproduce the behavior), or you've got a genuine bug. If you are feeling quite sure of yourself, I'd recommend opening a ticket with Microsoft to look into it.
